# Returns the smallest prime number that is a divisor of x

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, prime-factoring

The following code contains a mistake that can trigger an infinite loop,  I can not figure out how to get the second print statement to run, I am sure it is something simple to fix it, but just can't see it.

```
def smallest_prime_factor(x):
    """Returns the smallest prime number that is a divisor of x"""
    # Start checking with 2, then move up one by one
    n = 2
    while n <= x:
        if x % n == 0:
            x += 1
            return n

print(smallest_prime_factor(12)) # should be 2
print(smallest_prime_factor(15)) # should be 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get in an infinite loop because you do not change the value of  `n` if the return condition it is not met, as you can see the return condition is met only if your number `x` is a multiple of 2, you have to change :

```
if x % n == 0:
    x += 1
```

with:

```
while n <= x:
    if x % n == 0:
        return x
    n += 1
```

to optimize your code you can search for a number prime `n` to divide `x` that is less than `int(math.sqrt(x) + 1)`:

```
import math

def smallest_prime_factor(x):
    """Returns the smallest prime number that is a divisor of x"""
    # Start checking with 2, then move up one by one
    n = 2
    max_n = int(math.sqrt(x) + 1)
    while n < max_n:
        if x % n == 0:
            return n
        n += 1

    return x
```

even better you could use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to generate fast the  prime numbers and test against your x:

```
# Sieve of Eratosthenes
# Code by David Eppstein, UC Irvine, 28 Feb 2002
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119/

def gen_primes(y):
    """ Generate an infinite sequence of prime numbers.
    """
    # Maps composites to primes witnessing their compositeness.
    # This is memory efficient, as the sieve is not "run forward"
    # indefinitely, but only as long as required by the current
    # number being tested.
    #
    D = {}

    # The running integer that's checked for primeness
    q = 2

    while q < y:
        if q not in D:
            # q is a new prime.
            # Yield it and mark its first multiple that isn't
            # already marked in previous iterations
            # 
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            # q is composite. D[q] is the list of primes that
            # divide it. Since we've reached q, we no longer
            # need it in the map, but we'll mark the next 
            # multiples of its witnesses to prepare for larger
            # numbers
            # 
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]


def smallest_prime_factor(x):
    """Returns the smallest prime number that is a divisor of x"""
    # Start checking with 2, then move up one by one

    return next((i for i in gen_primes(int(math.sqrt(x) + 1)) if x % i == 0), x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of increasing value for `x` which is the number for which you are trying to find the smallest prime number factor, you need to increase `n` that is the factor. Also, if `n` divides `x`, then you need to return `n` else you need to increment the value of `n` outside the `if` block.

Try this code:

```
def smallest_prime_factor(x):
    """Returns the smallest prime number that is a divisor of x"""
    # Start checking with 2, then move up one by one
    n = 2
    while n <= x:
        if x % n == 0:
            return n
        n += 1
```

Also to optimize it more, you just need to run `while` loop till the square root of a number to find it's prime number factor, else the number itself is the prime factor.
So this is the optimized version of the above code:

```
def smallest_prime_factor(x):
    """Returns the smallest prime number that is a divisor of x"""
    # Start checking with 2, then move up one by one
    n = 2
    while n*n <= x:
        if x % n == 0:
            return n
        n += 1
    return x
```